# Is a canonical link to the HTTP page OK for a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-application

We are running a webshop and Google should index it on the normal HTTP pages.

But because there is also a "Facebook app" in front of the same shop, and a fb app requires https, all pages are reachable on HTTPS also.

The question is, if I add a `<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/thesame-page">` to all HTTPS pages, will this be ok for Facebook? (This link tag would be needed to avoid google seeing duplicate content iin our shop)

But this is a Facebook app question. Will Facebook just happily ignore it?

Comment: Should be because nothing is retrieved when using `<link rel="canonical">`. Canonical links work by informing search engines preferred pages and when users view a page with a canonical link nothing again is retrieved as its for search bots ;)

Comment: as in received, link canonical is information for search engines not a resource like a image, sound file or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my sites has all the canonical URLs pointing to the HTTP site, but the Facebook app available over HTTPS.   This appears to cause no problems for Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

As Facebook are not a website search engine, it is unlikely they need to use that tag for anything.  A search on Facebook's help centre for "canonical" certainly returns no results.

Pretty sure they will just ignore it.

Comment: thank you. feel voted up. i have not enough "reputation" for actually doing it.